# Is there anything specific I'll need to do to use a UserControl more than once in the same form?

Tags: wpf-controls

I'm creating a custom UserControl that's going to represent the form content of a TabItem. Basically, I'm using the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535868/wpf-adding-dynamic-controls-to-dynamically-added-tabitem). However, the UserControl I'm designing has several text fields, check boxes, etc. and I'm going to need to process this data to insert it into a SQL database. However, I'm designing the control now, and I want to make sure I won't run into problems over overlapping names once I start adding tabs with all of these text fields.

I guess my question is: is there something special I'll need to do to process these text fields? Basically I'll be looping through the TabItems, getting the data from each of their respective forms, and processing it.

I know this question is extremely general, but I'm extremely new to WPF (as this is my first day learning it) and I've already been tasked with writing a fully fledged application and I'm completely overwhelmed. Just trying to make sure I start off on the write tack! If there is any more information I should specify, please let me know and I'll do my best. I don't want this question closed immediately if I'm missing something, since I do desperately need it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a user control is the first step in a good approach.  Basically you will populate your control with all of the fields you plan to expose.  Your question about overlapping names is confusing considering that usually isn't something that happens in UI design unless you need to continue to display consistant, variable data across all of the tabs.

I would suggest you look into MVVM briefly but only from the standpoint of using a view model to bind the values to your fields.  Multiple fields with the same data isn't a problem if you have the control names in different controls.  However you must preface the user control name with each access of the control.  in other words:

```
pageOne.Title = "Fluid Temperatures";
pageTwo.Title = "Fluid flowrates";
pageThree.Title = "Fluid Viscosities";

pageOne.FluidName="Carbonic Acid";
pageTwo.FluidName="Carbonic Acid";
pageThree.FluidName="Carbonic Acid";
```

You will find the use of a viewmodel and two way data binding will make your life much easier.

Hope this helps in your situation.

Comment: Ah, ok. So even if I have a text box named `text_box_year` in each of, say, five tab pages, as long as I just loop through the tab pages and always preface my statements along these lines: `tabItem1.text_box_year`, `tabItem2.text_box_year`, etc. (I don't know if that's the syntax, but that's the general idea I think) I shouldn't run into many problems, right? It's not displaying the data that I worry about. It's fetching the data, which is entered by the user on the form, in the actual C# code.

Comment: Yup.  As long as you use qualified property names you are just fine.